# Helm install from stable got no available release name found error

Tags: linux, centos, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Installed a k8s cluster by `kubespray` with vagrant used its default [Vagrantfile](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray/blob/master/Vagrantfile) setting.

OS selected `centos`.

After the cluster setup finished, ran commands on master host:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"", Minor:"", GitVersion:"v1.9.0+coreos.0", GitCommit:"1b69a2a6c01194421b0aa17747a8c1a81738a8dd", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-12-19T02:52:15Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"", Minor:"", GitVersion:"v1.9.0+coreos.0", GitCommit:"1b69a2a6c01194421b0aa17747a8c1a81738a8dd", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-12-19T02:52:15Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Downloaded newest `Helm` from [github](https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-helm/helm-v2.8.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz).

```
$ ./helm init
$ ./helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.8.0", GitCommit:"14af25f1de6832228539259b821949d20069a222", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.8.0", GitCommit:"14af25f1de6832228539259b821949d20069a222", GitTreeState:"clean"}

$ ./helm search

...
stable/phpbb                    0.6.1           3.2.2           Community forum that supports the notion of use...
...

$ ./helm install stable/phpbb
Error: no available release name found
```

Why can't find when installing?

Comment: try using kubectl --namespace=kube-system edit deployment/tiller-deploy and change automountServiceAccountToken to true

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding --name my-release?